# Chrome Profile not updating DNS

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, dns, vpn

I know a lot of people might have asked this, but has anyone of you an idea on how to force a chrome profile to update its DNS?

Problem: My domain redirected to another domain for some time now. Now I changed it to redirect to my server.

When I open an private window in chrome (or in any other browser on my mac) the new server gets called. But when logged in to my Chrome Profile it doesn't work. It redirects to my old domain.

I already flushed the Chrome and my Macs DNS and Chrome's cache. I even installed the chrome extension of my VPN provider. When it's active, same story: I get my new server; when disabled, my old redirection comes along.

Any ideas?

Cheers from Berlin and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case some of you have the same problem:

In my case I had to change my Mac's (all machines) DNS server, flush DNS cache and also flush Chromes DNS cache.

Try it and restart your machine, if needed.
Hope this helps.